# Image with WLD file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, world-file

I have an image with a WLD file referenced in UTM (no PRJ file but I know the Zone). I want to overlay the image on OpenStreetMap. I have both as layers in QGIS and I have set the CRS for the image to ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_N32 but when I zoom to the image layer it shows the image off the south coast of France instead of in Germany. I can see that the location is just coincidence, the OpenStreetMap CRS location (in France) is numerically the same as the UTM location (in Germany) in the WLD file.

There are a couple of similar questions that imply that all I have to do is set the CRS of the layer to Zone 32 and QGIS will overlay the image on the OpenStreetMap image - but this does not work (for me).

Comment: Which CRS is the raster file supposed to be in? Which CRS did you set for your project?

Comment: Many data providers use "short" coordinates in ETRS89_UTM32N. They subtract 32,000,000 from the X. Try adding 32 million to the line 5 of your world file.

Comment: Erik: The Project is WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator, The Raster (PNG/PGW) file is UTM Zone 32

Comment: Pointdump: I tried your suggestion but that just moves the raster off the OpenStreetMap entirely.

Answer (score 1):

OK, got it working! The problem was the CRS for the raster - and the 32,000,000 mentioned by Pointdump. I used a different UTM Zone 32 CRS (*ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N (zE-N)* in place of *ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_N32*) and prefixed the X value with 32 and it worked.